# My camera application crashes while switching on it.

Tags: android, camera, heap-memory

While switching on my camera application i am getting the following command and it is going to close. I have added more code recognising the user voice command. The heap memory is creating the problem, but i am not able find the exact reason. Please help.

```
01-02 06:30:47.677: INFO/ActivityManager(291): app/in.co.my.android.camera[INITIAL] app.idle/false
01-02 06:30:47.677: INFO/ActivityManager(291): START {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=in.co.my.android.camera/.stillimagecamera.Camera} from pid 788
01-02 06:30:47.747: INFO/ActivityManager(291): app/in.co.my.android.camera[RESUMED] app.idle/false ...realStartActivityLocked
01-02 06:30:47.747: INFO/CameraBaseActivity(14632): onCreate start
01-02 06:30:47.755: DEBUG/IntentParameters(14632): DCFsaveCapture=false, ImageCapture=false
01-02 06:30:47.755: DEBUG/IntentParameters(14632): SaveUri=null, CropValue=null, CameraStyle=0
01-02 06:30:48.005: DEBUG/in.co.my.android.camera.stillimagecamera.RecognizerTask(14632): waiting
01-02 06:30:48.005: INFO/ActivityManager(291): app/com.google.android.tts[INITIAL] app.idle/false
01-02 06:30:48.005: INFO/ActivityManager(291): START {act=android.speech.tts.engine.CHECK_TTS_DATA cmp=com.google.android.tts/.CheckVoiceData} from pid 14632
01-02 06:30:48.013: DEBUG/Camera(14632): onCreateImpl start
01-02 06:30:48.052: INFO/CameraBaseActivity(14632): onContentChanged
01-02 06:30:48.060: DEBUG/Camera(14632): onCreateImpl end
01-02 06:30:48.060: DEBUG/Camera(14632): [ 01-02 06:30:48.091 14632:0x3931 F/libc     ]
01-02 06:30:48.060: DEBUG/Camera(14632): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0xe8a4a3f4 (code=1)
01-02 06:30:48.513: INFO/ActivityManager(291): app/com.google.android.tts[RESUMED] app.idle/false ...realStartActivityLocked
01-02 06:30:48.513: WARN/ActivityManager(291): Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{41c69028 in.co.my.android.camera/.stillimagecamera.Camera}
01-02 06:30:48.521: INFO/ActivityManager(291): app/in.co.my.android.camera[RESUMED] app.idle/false ...resumeTopActivityLocked
01-02 06:30:48.599: INFO/DEBUG(13939): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
01-02 06:30:48.599: INFO/DEBUG(13939): Build fingerprint: 'SBM/SBM104SH/SBM104SH:4.0.3/A3080/00.00.00:eng/test-keys'
01-02 06:30:48.599: INFO/DEBUG(13939): pid: 14632, tid: 14641  >>> in.co.my.android.camera <<<
01-02 06:30:48.599: INFO/DEBUG(13939): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr e8a4a3f4
01-02 06:30:48.599: INFO/DEBUG(13939):  r0 40124b34  r1 008f4000  r2 e8a4a3e8  r3 00ad53d8
01-02 06:30:48.599: INFO/DEBUG(13939):  r4 00b81a38  r5 00aadac8  r6 00000158  r7 00000001
01-02 06:30:48.599: INFO/DEBUG(13939):  r8 00aa01d0  r9 00000025  10 00000008  fp     5b443c04
01-02 06:30:48.599: INFO/DEBUG(13939):  ip 00000158  sp 5b443b90  lr 400ed8fc  pc 400f1102  cpsr a0000030
01-02 06:30:48.599: INFO/DEBUG(13939):  d0  0000000000000000  d1  0000000000000000
01-02 06:30:48.599: INFO/DEBUG(13939):  d2  00000003786e6968  d3  6e6968707374656b
01-02 06:30:48.599: INFO/DEBUG(13939):  d4  41d2d7d841d48bd8  d5  41b07ac841c0aec0
01-02 06:30:48.599: INFO/DEBUG(13939):  d6  3cea65d400000000  d7  fffffffe4188c4d0
01-02 06:30:48.599: INFO/DEBUG(13939):  d8  0000000000000000  d9  0000000000000000
01-02 06:30:48.599: INFO/DEBUG(13939):  d10 0000000000000000  d11 0000000000000000
01-02 06:30:48.599: INFO/DEBUG(13939):  d12 0000000000000000  d13 0000000000000000
01-02 06:30:48.599: INFO/DEBUG(13939):  d14 0000000000000000  d15 0000000000000000
01-02 06:30:48.599: INFO/DEBUG(13939):  d16 3fb9750000000000  d17 3fdfffffffffffcb
01-02 06:30:48.599: INFO/DEBUG(13939):  d18 3fe0000000000000  d19 3fe000000000001a
01-02 06:30:48.599: INFO/DEBUG(13939):  d20 0000000000000000  d21 0000000000000000
01-02 06:30:48.599: INFO/DEBUG(13939):  d22 0000000000000000  d23 0000000000000000
01-02 06:30:48.599: INFO/DEBUG(13939):  d24 0000000000000000  d25 0000000000000000
01-02 06:30:48.599: INFO/DEBUG(13939):  d26 0000000000000000  d27 0000000000000000
01-02 06:30:48.599: INFO/DEBUG(13939):  d28 0100010001000100  d29 0100010001000100
01-02 06:30:48.599: INFO/DEBUG(13939):  d30 0000000000000000  d31 3fe7fffff4000005
01-02 06:30:48.599: INFO/DEBUG(13939):  scr 20000012
01-02 06:30:48.724: INFO/DEBUG(13939):          #00  pc 00016102  /system/lib/libc.so (dlfree)
01-02 06:30:48.724: INFO/DEBUG(13939):          #01  pc 00016798  /system/lib/libc.so (free)
01-02 06:30:48.724: INFO/DEBUG(13939):          #02  pc 0006bcf0  /system/lib/libicuuc.so (uprv_free_46)
01-02 06:30:48.724: INFO/DEBUG(13939):          #03  pc 00051a24  /system/lib/libicuuc.so (uscript_closeRun_46)
01-02 06:30:48.724: INFO/DEBUG(13939):          #04  pc 000a7d42  /system/lib/libicui18n.so (_ZN6icu_4612RegexPattern3zapEv)
01-02 06:30:48.724: INFO/DEBUG(13939):          #05  pc 000a7d72  /system/lib/libicui18n.so (_ZN6icu_4612RegexPatternD2Ev)
01-02 06:30:48.732: INFO/DEBUG(13939):          #06  pc 000a7d94  /system/lib/libicui18n.so (_ZN6icu_4612RegexPatternD0Ev)
01-02 06:30:48.732: INFO/DEBUG(13939):          #07  pc 000106b2  /system/lib/libnativehelper.so
01-02 06:30:48.732: INFO/DEBUG(13939):          #08  pc 0001ebb0  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmPlatformInvoke)
01-02 06:30:48.732: INFO/DEBUG(13939):          #09  pc 0005822e  /system/lib/libdvm.so (_Z16dvmCallJNIMethodPKjP6JValuePK6MethodP6Thread)
01-02 06:30:48.732: INFO/DEBUG(13939): code around pc:
01-02 06:30:48.732: INFO/DEBUG(13939): 400f10e0 60a460e4 4854e01e 44784954 e0174479  .`.`..THTIxDyD..
01-02 06:30:48.732: INFO/DEBUG(13939): 400f10f0 689a4853 69014478 d308428b d306428a  SH.hxD.i.B...B..
01-02 06:30:48.732: INFO/DEBUG(13939): 400f1100 60d4609c 60e360a2 61a32300 484de00a  .`.`.`.`.#.a..MH
01-02 06:30:48.732: INFO/DEBUG(13939): 400f1110 4478494d e0034479 494d484c 44794478  MIxDyD..LHMIxDyD
01-02 06:30:48.732: INFO/DEBUG(13939): 400f1120 fe34f7fd 4478484b 11b4f8d0 d503078b  ..4.KHxD........
01-02 06:30:48.732: INFO/DEBUG(13939): code around lr:
01-02 06:30:48.732: INFO/DEBUG(13939): 400ed8dc e2166903 1a000018 e5945000 e1a02004  .i.......P... ..
01-02 06:30:48.732: INFO/DEBUG(13939): 400ed8ec e2055a02 e1a00005 e3851001 ebffecd7  .Z..............
01-02 06:30:48.732: INFO/DEBUG(13939): 400ed8fc e3500000 13856002 1a000001 ea000009  ..P..`..........
01-02 06:30:48.732: INFO/DEBUG(13939): 400ed90c ebfffe87 e1a01004 e1a00006 ebffecd7  ................
01-02 06:30:48.732: INFO/DEBUG(13939): 400ed91c e1a01005 e1a02006 e3a03000 e1550000  ..... ...0....U.
01-02 06:30:48.732: INFO/DEBUG(13939): memory map around addr e8a4a3f4:
01-02 06:30:48.732: INFO/DEBUG(13939): be952000-be973000 [stack]
01-02 06:30:48.732: INFO/DEBUG(13939): (no map for address)
01-02 06:30:48.732: INFO/DEBUG(13939): ffff0000-ffff1000 [vectors]
01-02 06:30:48.732: INFO/DEBUG(13939): stack:
01-02 06:30:48.732: INFO/DEBUG(13939):     5b443b50  00c8fb10  [heap]
01-02 06:30:48.732: INFO/DEBUG(13939):     5b443b54  40124b78  
01-02 06:30:48.732: INFO/DEBUG(13939):     5b443b58  00000020  
01-02 06:30:48.732: INFO/DEBUG(13939):     5b443b5c  40124b34  
01-02 06:30:48.732: INFO/DEBUG(13939):     5b443b60  00c8fb18  [heap]
01-02 06:30:48.732: INFO/DEBUG(13939):     5b443b64  50ba1f64  
01-02 06:30:48.732: INFO/DEBUG(13939):     5b443b68  00b9b170  [heap]
01-02 06:30:48.739: INFO/DEBUG(13939):     5b443b6c  40124b90  
01-02 06:30:48.739: INFO/DEBUG(13939):     5b443b70  00000000  
01-02 06:30:48.739: INFO/DEBUG(13939):     5b443b74  00b87a08  [heap]
01-02 06:30:48.739: INFO/DEBUG(13939):     5b443b78  00000000  
01-02 06:30:48.739: INFO/DEBUG(13939):     5b443b7c  50ba1f6c  
01-02 06:30:48.739: INFO/DEBUG(13939):     5b443b80  00b81a40  [heap]
01-02 06:30:48.739: INFO/DEBUG(13939):     5b443b84  50ba1f64  
01-02 06:30:48.739: INFO/DEBUG(13939):     5b443b88  df0027ad  
01-02 06:30:48.739: INFO/DEBUG(13939):     5b443b8c  00000000  
01-02 06:30:48.739: INFO/DEBUG(13939): #00 5b443b90  00000000  
01-02 06:30:48.739: INFO/DEBUG(13939):     5b443b94  00b87a08  [heap]
01-02 06:30:48.739: INFO/DEBUG(13939):     5b443b98  00000000  
01-02 06:30:48.739: INFO/DEBUG(13939):     5b443b9c  50ba1f6c  
01-02 06:30:48.739: INFO/DEBUG(13939):     5b443ba0  5b443bf0  
01-02 06:30:48.739: INFO/DEBUG(13939):     5b443ba4  50ba1f64  
01-02 06:30:48.739: INFO/DEBUG(13939):     5b443ba8  00000008  
01-02 06:30:48.739: INFO/DEBUG(13939):     5b443bac  400f179b  /system/lib/libc.so
01-02 06:30:48.739: INFO/DEBUG(13939): #01 5b443bb0  00000000  
01-02 06:30:48.739: INFO/DEBUG(13939):     5b443bb4  404d9cf3  /system/lib/libicuuc.so
01-02 06:30:49.958: DEBUG/OEM_RIL(486): <<< [UNSL] Unknown ID: -4
01-02 06:30:51.107: INFO/BootReceiver(291): Copying /data/tombstones/tombstone_05 to  DropBox (SYSTEM_TOMBSTONE)
01-02 06:30:51.169: WARN/Process(291): Unable to open /proc/14632/status
01-02 06:30:51.169: WARN/Process(291): Unable to open /proc/14632/status
01-02 06:30:51.169: WARN/Process(291): Unable to open /proc/14632/status
01-02 06:30:51.169: INFO/ActivityManager(291): handleAppDiedLocked, call sendFinishPackageName. Exception/true
01-02 06:30:51.169: INFO/ActivityManager(291): Process in.co.my.android.camera (pid 14632) has died.
01-02 06:30:51.169: WARN/ActivityManager(291): Force removing ActivityRecord{41c69028 in.co.my.android.camera/.stillimagecamera.Camera}: app died, no saved state
01-02 06:30:51.177: WARN/Process(291): Unable to open /proc/14632/status
01-02 06:30:51.177: WARN/Process(291): Unable to open /proc/14632/status
01-02 06:30:51.177: WARN/Process(291): Unable to open /proc/14632/status
01-02 06:30:51.177: WARN/Process(291): Unable to open /proc/14632/status
01-02 06:30:51.177: WARN/Process(291): Unable to open /proc/14632/status
01-02 06:30:51.185: INFO/ActivityManager(291): app/in.co.my.android.home[RESUMED] app.idle/true ...resumeTopActivityLocked
01-02 06:30:51.294: INFO/Launcher(788): onResume() serviceIf == null
01-02 06:30:51.294: WARN/ActivityManager(291): Unable to start service Intent { act=in.co.my.android.home.IInfosignAidlService typ=application/vnd.my.mail }: not found
01-02 06:30:51.302: WARN/InputManagerService(291): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@41c659e0
01-02 06:30:51.552: INFO/ActivityManager(291): removeActivityFromHistoryLocked, call sendFinishPackageName.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you got the correct permission flag in your manifest file for camera?